# How and where register npm installed component for VueJS

Tags: vue.js, npm, components, vue-component, vuejs3

I created a Vuejs project using `vue create` command provided after installing `npm i @vue/cli`. Now in my project I want to use [this component](https://vue-select.org/). In it's installation guide it says:
"Then, import and register the component:"

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import vSelect from 'vue-select'

Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)
```

But where? None of my `main.js` files does not even include `Vue from 'vue'`

Comment: This is the documentation for how you imported components globally in Vue2. So I am not sure this component is Vue3 compatible if they didn't update the documentation accordingly.

Comment: https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/1251

Answer (score 0):

In vuejs3, you can use like this in `main.js`

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

createApp(App).component('v-select', vSelect).mount("#app");
```

doc: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-registration.html